# Craft CMS issue with Composer V2

Tags: craft3, composer

We have a website built in Craft 3.4.14 and we are moving it to a hosting company with CentOS 7, using Plesk Obsidian 18.0.5.

The hosting company has told us that they have upgraded Composer from version 1 to version 2. On my local machine I have been using version 1.10. However, I try to run Composer on the server and I get these issues: -

- craftcms/plugin-installer 1.5.3 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match your constraint.
- craftcms/plugin-installer 1.5.4 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match your constraint.
- craftcms/cms 3.4.14 requires craftcms/plugin-installer ~1.5.3 -> satisfiable by craftcms/plugin-installer[1.5.4, 1.5.3].
- Root composer.json requires craftcms/cms 3.4.14 -> satisfiable by craftcms/cms[3.4.14].

Is there a way around these issues so that we can get Craft CMS installed please?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Composer 2 support has been drafted over at [craftcms/plugin-installer#4](https://github.com/craftcms/plugin-installer/pull/4). We’ll merge that in once Composer 2 is officially released.

~~In the meantime, if you really need to get Craft working with Composer 2, follow the instructions at [craftcms/plugin-installer#3](https://github.com/craftcms/plugin-installer/issues/3#issuecomment-613959587).~~

**UPDATE:** `craftcms/plugin-installer` and `yiisoft/yii2-composer` have both been updated to support Composer 2.

Comment: Composer 2 has now been released and plenty of plugins are incompatible, including core plugins like Amazon S3 and redactor.

Comment: @jishi just run `composer update` so you get the latest version of `craftcms/plugin-installer`

Comment: Ah, yes. So it seems. My bad!